# Several different leaflet maps on same page

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, gpx

I like to draw several different small segments (gpx-files), each on a separate leaflet map

With this code I tried to write around the problem, that leaflet needs a new layer for map

I used the "layers"-array to store all map references...

```
<script>
    var layers = [];
    var i = 0;
    var ref;
</script>
@for(segment <- segments) {
    <div id="@segment.id" style="height:300px"></div>
    <script>
        layers[i] = L.map("@segment.id");

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        }).addTo(layers[i]);

        var url = '/assets/gpx_files/@segment.gpxPath';

        new L.GPX(url, {
            async: true,
            marker_options: {
                startIconUrl: '/assets/images/pinIcon.png',
                endIconUrl: '/assets/images/pinIcon.png',
                shadowUrl: '/assets/images/pinIconShadow.png'
            }
        }).on('loaded', function(e) {
            layers[i].fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
        }).addTo(layers[i]);
        i = i+1;
    </script>
```

(I have a "layers"-array which stores a new layer for every segment, because leaflet cannot handle it otherwise)

But leaflet doesn't like

```
layer[i].fitBounds
```

-> TypeError: layers[i] is undefined

Has anyone a good idea for me?

Comment: Can you place in a `console.log(layers)` prior to the line throwing the error so we can see whats going on here?Or better yet, can you place this in an online demo? Is a map container being created at all?Is @segment.id being interpolated correctly?

Comment: I built a small example, but i didn't found a way to link a gpx-file. http://jsbin.com/xovuseqata/2/edit?html,css,output
If you replace the line "var ref = layers[i];" with "layers[i]"  the problem appears, currently only the last map shows the track. 

I tested @segment.id and it's definitely correctly working.

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't be including Leaflet 0.5 and Mapbox 2.1.9 on the same page. Drop the `http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.5/leaflet.js` reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error with trying to call fitBounds on a undefined object..
This codeblock here resolves the issue. Notice how I pass the map reference(`ref:ref`) to GPX in its options hash so I can clearly retrieve it later as opposed to trying to grab it via index.The GPX retrieval action is async, and there is no guarantee when it will finish, so you need to be aware of that. This code takes that delay out of the equation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx/master/gpx.js"></script>

<div id="map0" style="height:300px"></div>
<div id="map1" style="height:300px"></div>
<div id="map2" style="height:300px"></div>
<div id="map3" style="height:300px"></div>
<script>
var layers = [];
var i = 0;
var map = "map";
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
  layers[i] = L.map(map.concat(i));
  var ref = layers[i];
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  }).addTo(ref);

  var url = 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/run.gpx';

  new L.GPX(url, {
    ref:ref,
    async: true
  }).on('loaded', function(e) {
 e.target.options.ref.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }).addTo(ref);
}
</script>
```

See output @ http://output.jsbin.com/yazafuvika/1/